# Rails does not appear to hit my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, erb

When I go through this with debugger, it does no  hit the controller.

I get the following error:

> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

i.e. `@user` is nil. `@user` is nil even if I set it to find the first one via `@user = @Users.first`

I want to access the user via domain.com/id

Routes.rb

```
match ':id' => 'user#show'
```

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :userLink, :userName
end
```

Controller controllers/user_controller.rb

```
def Show
    @user= User.find_by_id params[:id]
    # Attempted this with User.first to see if param was broken    

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.json { render json: @user}
    end
end
```

View file name views/user/show.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%=  @user.id %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

`def Show` in your controllers should be `def show`

Comment: Thank you! I'm use to C# and writing my methods with caps!

Comment: I transitioned from java, using [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/) on my code base helped a lot to be more in the "ruby" way. Note also that match is consider "unsafe". If your project is open source, take a look at [pullreview](http://pullreview.com)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the tool suggestions! Those look like really useful tools. It is so easy to make these minute errors coming from a statically typed language and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify route like this

Just replace this

```
match ':id' => 'user#show'
```

with

```
resources :users, only: [:show]
```

This will generate default route for you for show method

Comment: I like this style: `resources :users, only: [:show]` I will update my code with the styling since it's clear and avoids these types of mistakes.

Comment: Yes, its better rails style.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
match '/:id' => 'user#show'
```

but this is not a good approach as many of your routes will be disabled by that 
like if you have **www.yourdomain.com/profile** will also goes to your show action.

also def Show here **Show should be show**

Comment: I purposely disabled the other paths. My app that I am building only needs to create and show the user object. I don't want the user to have control of deleting or updating the User data. Thanks for the advice though since I am a rails newbie.Though I may rethink it if I decide to add in an administrator setting for myself.